# Working with UTF-8 characters, Java

Tags: java, maven, unicode, encoding, utf-8

My basic code is trying to check files exitence, based on paths, but it can't deal with Unicode Characters:

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        File f = new File(input);
        if (f.exists()) {
            System.out.println("File is Found, According to java.io");
        } else {
            System.out.println(f.toString() + " is Not Existed, According to java.io ");
        }

        Path x = Paths.get(input);
        if (Files.exists(x)) {
            System.out.println("File is Found, According to java.nio");
        } else {
            System.out.println(x.toString() + " is Not Existed, According to java.nio");
        }
```

when the input (ie. file path) is in ASCII, the code works fine, but when the input contains UTF-8 chars, the code fails in both :

1- printing the input properly.

2- determining does the file exist (ie. even when the file exists, the code tells that file is not exited)

Example:

**input:**

> c://€.jpg

**output:**

> c:\�.jpg is Not Existed, According to java.io
>
> c:\�.jpg is Not Existed, According to java.nio

I use NetBeans, Java 1.8, maven.

**PS**: I tried to use:

run with :

**-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8**

add the followign to project properties :

```
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
```

, but nothing happened.

Any help, please?

Comment: The problem is that you need to use the proper input encoding, so the string is correct.  Check with a debugger that `input`  contains exactly what you expect when set.  You will probably be surprised.

Answer (score 1):

Precisely, you don't need a file encoding, but an input encoding. Therefore you can specify a charset for your `Scanner` using the [`Scanner(InputStream source, String charsetName)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String)) constructor:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: sorry, but nothing has changed.

Comment: @Nosairat Try piping your input from a text file that you encode in UTF-8. It's likely that the encodings for your terminal and Scanner are not in alignment or don't support the characters that you are trying to use.